# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline - how to load Parameters value immediately in the first next build?

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins Declarative pipeline with one Parameter - DEPLOY_ENV.
It has default value **staging**:

- if I run it for the first time this will fail because no parameters have been loaded yet
- if I run it for the second time it will run the pipeline and print correct value **staging**
- if I change value in script to **test** and run it it will print **staging**
- if I run it once again it will print the value **test** because only then is the value changed in the parameters list of this build configuration

I do not want to change value manually in the Build Configuration because at that point I must run Build immediately in order to preserve that value. My all builds are being executed only automatically (checkout on new code change)

- I would like either to change value in script and to be applicable immediately in the first next run
- or to change the value in "Build with Parameters" but not to run the Build only to Save it for the next first run
- In View Configuration the value is read only so I cannot change it.

How I can change the value and to be applicable immediately for the first next build?
Thanks!!!

```
pipeline {
    parameters {
        string (name: 'DEPLOY_ENV', defaultValue:'staging')
    }
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('echo stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh "echo $DEPLOY_ENV"

                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically change the default value of `DEPLOY_ENV` inside your pipeline using `properties` and set it to `test` after the first build. A possible solution:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('echo stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (env.BUILD_NUMBER.toInteger() == 1) {
                        env.DEPLOY_ENV = 'staging'
                    }
                    echo env.DEPLOY_ENV
                    properties([
                        parameters([
                            string (name: 'DEPLOY_ENV', defaultValue: 'test')
                        ])
                    ])
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

With this solution:

- First build prints `staging`
- Second build prints `test` (default value of `DELOY_ENV` is equal to `test`)

Comment: Hi Brahim, thank for your efforts and kind assistance
but with this solution if I want to change the value of DEPLOY_ENV again to for example `production` value I will not be able to do it if `DEPLOY_ENV` is defined within the parameters segment, correct?